# Mean quantity added to bucket per time step, using Markov chain.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Imagine we have a bucket and a finite set of increasingly sized cups. Over time, we add and subtract water from the bucket. At each time step we either add or subtract water with equal (50/50) probability using one of the cups. The cup used at each time step is determined according to a set of probabilities over the cups. The cup size probabilities do not depend on the water level of the bucket. However, for each time step, if the remaining bucket capacity (or remaining water in the bucket) is less than the chosen cup size, then the water added (or removed) will be equal to the remaining capacity (or water). We can assume that the bucket is initially empty.

Over infinite time, what is the average amount of water added to the bucket per time step, where water removed counts as zero. What is the most efficient way to compute or approximate this?

To compute it exactly, I think the problem can be dissolved into four steps:

1. Given the bucket and cup sizes, what is the state space (the set of possible water volumes)?
2. What are the transition probabilities for each state?
3. What is the expected quantity of water added for each state?
4. What fraction of the time will the bucket be in each state?

Two and three are easy. One seems like it gets very messy with many cups that aren't factors of one another. Four I don't know the math to solve.

Comment: So you have some cups of finite size and a bucket. Does the bucket have a finite capacity? Either way, how much water is initially in the bucket? In any case it seems like you can define the state space just in terms of the volumes of water in each container, each separately as continuous variables. Some of the states may not be accessible (this happens if the cups are all multiples of some fixed size and the total amount of water is also a multiple of that size, for instance) but that's not a problem except for computational purposes.

Comment: (Cont.) Without such an assumption I'm pretty sure that eventually weird things can happen, where cups wind up only partially filled, which can cause the set of accessible states to become quite large.

Comment: @Ian I edited the question for clarity. I think you're right about the set of accessible states becoming quite large.

Comment: Oh, so the *cups* are initially full and the bucket is initially empty. That makes sense. But it still allows for partially-filled cups, provided the bucket is smaller than the total volume of the cups. And partially-filled cups allow things to really balloon in size.

Comment: @Ian Sorry, no. The cups are always full. They are replenished at each time step from an infinite source. The cups just represent the amount that is added or removed at each step.

Comment: So the state is actually entirely the state of the bucket, and a cup always is poured into the bucket if it is chosen unless its contents won't fit?

Comment: @Ian Exactly. And if the contents won't fit, then the the partial contents of the cup that will fit is poured in.

Comment: But then in this case the cup is fully refilled from the external reservoir, so you arrive at the "everything is full" state? What happens from this state? Or is it just absorbing?

Comment: @Ian We have a %50 chance to remove water with the cup. If we are removing water, then the cups are empty to begin with. So when the bucket is full, we can still remove water. The only two things you need to keep track of are how much water is in the bucket, and what is the size of the cup.

Comment: OK. So at any given time, you can either: add min(x_i,remaining_capacity) to the bucket, or remove min(x_i,current_contents) from the bucket, where x_i is some arbitrary finite set of positive real numbers. Yeah that is quite the complicated process unless the x_i are all rational multiples of some fixed x. If you even have two rational-linearly independent x_i then lots of weird things can happen.

Comment: @Ian Yeah. I thought so. Perhaps you can recommend a way to simplify the problem with an approximate model? For example, perhaps we should say that, at each step, the volume in the bucket is rounded to the nearest milliliter.